# What's causing this error when running a web worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

First time using web workers and I get this error when I try to run it.

First I get a very generic error event sent to my `worker.onerror` handler. It does not have the `message` property, the only information is the property `type` which says error.

Looking at the network tab in dev tools, the request for the worker script looks like it succeeds but it only has provisional response headers and no content to preview.

Preview has:

> failed to load response data: connection is closed, can't dispatch pending call to Network.getResponseBody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This caused me to waste about an hour searching for web worker errors. Anyway it turns out that you can get this error if you have a syntax error in your Javascript. At least that is what got me.